# Dynamically call overridden function

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

I iterate through a list and want to call a function on each item, but this function should be replaceable.

For example I have the following script:

```
class Parent(object):
    def a(self, text):
        raise NotImplementedError("called Parent.a")
    def b(self, text):
        raise NotImplementedError("called Parent.b")

class ChildA(Parent):
    def a(self, text):
        return "A.a: {}".format(text)
    def b(self, text):
        return "A.b: {}".format(text)

class ChildB(Parent):
    def a(self, text):
        return "B.a: {}".format(text)
    def b(self, text):
        return "B.b: {}".format(text)

# the separation is ONLY so that the first exec_all doesn't fail
# in my production code it's a list of mixed instances
children = [ 
    ChildA(), # obviously here might be several different ChildA instances
]
childrenMixed = children + [
    ChildB(), # obviously here might be several different ChildB instances
]

def exec_all(method, children):
    for child in children:
        try:
            print(method(child, "Hello world"))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Unable to call method for child '{}': {}".format(child, e.message))

exec_all(ChildA.a, children) # works
exec_all(ChildA.b, children) # works
exec_all(ChildA.a, childrenMixed) # TypeError
exec_all(ChildA.b, childrenMixed) # TypeError
exec_all(Parent.a, childrenMixed) # NotImplementError
exec_all(Parent.b, childrenMixed) # NotImplementError
```

The first two `exec_all` does work fine, but the next two don't work, because it tries to call `ChildA.a` which doesn't exists in `ChildB`. And the last two raise the `NotImplementedError`.

It should look something like this:

```
A.a: Hello world # 1st exec_all
A.b: Hello world # 2nd exec_all
A.a: Hello world # 3rd exec_all
B.a: Hello world # but TypeError
A.b: Hello world # 4th exec_all 
B.b: Hello world # but TypeError
A.a: Hello world # 5th exec_all
B.a: Hello world # but NotImplementError
A.b: Hello world # 6th exec_all 
B.b: Hello world # but NotImplementError
```

So how do I support multiple subclasses of `Parent`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle : "Subclassing is substitutability." If your subclasses are not substitutable, then you are not using subclassing correctly. And it seems that `Parent` is abstract and should have no instances, so a class that has no instances should not present a problem.

Comment: On a separate note, you should not do this: `additional=[]`. Do this instead: `def exec_all(method, additional=None): additional = additional or []`.

Comment: @hughdbrown: His subclasses are substitutable for `Parent`; the problem is that he's trying to substitute a `ChildB` for a `ChildA`, and there is no subclass relationship there. Which he can fix by just using `Parent.a` instead of `ChildA.a`.

Comment: @hughdbrown: On your second note, since he's not mutating `additional`, it really doesn't matter… But it definitely is worth him learning the idiom, and why it exists, so it was worth bringing up.

Comment: First of all it's a mockup the complete code is a bit more complex. And them I'm wondering how would you solve it then? This is pretty much text book OOP: I have multiple classes with the same method and the for loop shouldn't care if it's ChildA or ChildB. If that loop would only use `Parent.a` I could replace `method(…)` with `child.a("Hello world")`.

Comment: @xZise: Yes, this is textbook OOP, and the loop shouldn't care if it's `ChildA` or `ChildB` or even some type defined in another module, as long as it's a subclass of `Parent`. That's why you should pass it `Parent.a`. By passing it `ChildA.a`, you're _forcing_ it to care whether it's `ChildA` or `ChildB`, which is exactly the problem.

Comment: @xZise: What is the desired behavior?

Comment: For the first `A.a` the second `A.b`. The third and fifth should both return `A.a, B.a` and the fourth and sixth `A.b, B.b`. It's simplified, each <letter>.<letter> combination is in it's own row and followed by “: Hello world”.

Comment: @abarnert that 3rd and 4th are failing is expected but when I remove them, comment them out or catch the exceptions as I did in the latest version it'll try the 5th and 6th but crash there, because it calls the Parent methods.

Comment: @xZise: So do you want something like unutbu's suggestion, separating the method name and object type, allowing you to call any combinaton of object type and method name (except the Parent that is abstract and not intended to be called)?

Comment: @seb: I would like to avoid using a string to determine the method name. And for example in Java, it would execute the method of ChildA or ChildB when I have a variable which holds an instance which extends from Parent. If course Java doesn't support method "pointers" so it's not really applicable to this problem here. Basically I have an instance (which extends from Parent) and want to execute a method which all instances from Parent must have and I want to choose that method like a method "pointer".

Answer (score 2):

Are you after something like this?

```
exec_all(lambda x: x.a())
```

or:

```
def call_a(obj):
    return obj.a()
exec_all(call_a)
```

Comment: That works… but if you're going to do that, there is no reason for `Parent` and the whole subclass hierarchy at all.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the method name, not the method. Use [`getattr(child, methodname)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to obtain the method:

```
class Parent(object):
    def a(self, text):
        raise NotImplementedError("called Parent.a")
    def b(self, text):
        raise NotImplementedError("called Parent.b")

class ChildA(Parent):
    def a(self, text):
        return "A.a: {}".format(text)
    def b(self, text):
        return "A.b: {}".format(text)

class ChildB(Parent):
    def a(self, text):
        return "B.a: {}".format(text)
    def b(self, text):
        return "B.b: {}".format(text)

children = [ ChildA(), ]
childrenMixed = children + [ ChildB(), ]

def exec_all(methodname, children):
    for child in children:
        method = getattr(child, methodname)
        print(method("Hello world"))
    print

exec_all('a', children) 
exec_all('b', children) 
exec_all('a', childrenMixed) 
exec_all('b', childrenMixed) 
exec_all('a', childrenMixed) 
exec_all('b', childrenMixed)
```

yields

```
A.a: Hello world

A.b: Hello world

A.a: Hello world
B.a: Hello world

A.b: Hello world
B.b: Hello world

A.a: Hello world
B.a: Hello world

A.b: Hello world
B.b: Hello world
```

---

In Python2, `ChildA.a` is an *unbound* method. Unlike Python3, unbound methods check if the first argument is an instance of the correct class -- in this case `ChildA`. This is why calling

```
ChildA.a(ChildB(), text)
```

raises the `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: unbound method a() must be called with ChildA instance as first argument (got ChildB instance instead)
```

In Python3, such a call would be okay, though if you are doing this it would probably be better to make all these methods plain functions rather than methods.

---

It sounds like you really want to preserve the form of your function calls as you posted them:

```
exec_all(ChildA.a, children) 
exec_all(ChildA.b, children) 
exec_all(ChildA.a, childrenMixed) 
exec_all(ChildA.b, childrenMixed) 
exec_all(Parent.a, childrenMixed) 
exec_all(Parent.b, childrenMixed)
```

If we take this as a fixed requirement, then you could get the desired behavior by defining `exec_all` as follows:

```
class Parent(object):
    def a(self, text):
        raise NotImplementedError("called Parent.a")
    def b(self, text):
        raise NotImplementedError("called Parent.b")

class ChildA(Parent):
    def a(self, text):
        return "A.a: {}".format(text)
    def b(self, text):
        return "A.b: {}".format(text)

class ChildB(Parent):
    def a(self, text):
        return "B.a: {}".format(text)
    def b(self, text):
        return "B.b: {}".format(text)

children = [ 
    ChildA(), 
]
childrenMixed = children + [
    ChildB(), 
]

def exec_all(method, children):
    methodname = method.__name__
    for child in children:
        method = getattr(child, methodname)
        print(method("Hello world"))

exec_all(ChildA.a, children) 
exec_all(ChildA.b, children) 
exec_all(ChildA.a, childrenMixed) 
exec_all(ChildA.b, childrenMixed) 
exec_all(Parent.a, childrenMixed) 
exec_all(Parent.b, childrenMixed)
```

But passing the wrong method on purpose is not a good design. You shouldn't pass `ChildA.a` when you want `ChildB.a` to be called. Python does not make this simple because this is not the way OOP is intended to work. 
Either passing the **correct** methods or passing method names as strings (as shown above) are better options.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Whenever possible, it's much better to do it within the language (`lambda x: x.a()`) than by passing around strings.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. This seems to allow calling methods on any child object. Now we can argue on lambda or method names, but it seems to answer the question.

Comment: @seb: Presumably whoever downvoted it did so because he agreed with my comment. There are many downsides to using names instead of values in Python; in some cases, you have to do it, so you do it, but otherwise, you don't.